# How do I get a view of all recent activity in all the Stack Exchange sites I'm participating in

Tags: support, stackexchange.com

I am participating in about eight different Stack Exchange sites. How do I get a single view of all recent activity relevant to what I've posted in all the Stack Exchange sites?

I'm specifically looking for other answers in questions that I've participated, comments in questions I've participated in, edits to answers I've provided and reputation changes in answers I've participated in.

I can generally see this for one Stack Exchange site. I get the fleeting reply notification across all Stack Exchange sites at the top of my screen, but it's gone as soon as I look at anything and it only seems to cover some types of activity, and I can't find any way to ever look at that again once it's gone.

For new questions, I can set of an elaborate filter (which Stack Exchange sites, which tags) of what new questions I might be interested in (and have done so), but I can't figure out how to similarly see relevant activity across Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 5):

> How do I get a single view of all recent activity relevant to what I've posted in all the stacks?

Visit [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com). You'll find everything there, right in your profile, under *Activity*:

[image]

> I'm specifically looking for other answers in questions that I've participated, comments in questions I've participated in, edits to answers I've provided and reputation changes in answers I've participated in.

You can add questions to your favorites – as usual – and they will be displayed on your Stack Exchange account under *Profile » Favorites*  too. Also, your reputation change is recorded for the whole network, right under *Profile » Reputation*.

The *Activity* section features more of what you ask for, but not everything is covered (yet).

> I can set of an elaborate filter (which stacks, which tags) of what new questions I might be interested in (and have done so), but can't figure out how to similar see relevant activity across stacks

Under "Tagged Questions", you can set filters for your favorite tags across all sites, and browse them right there. You can also look for popular filters, or add your own combinations.

[image]